# Gerar imagem dinamicamente por url

Tags: php, placeholder

Como eu faço para criar em PHP com o intervention um servidor de imagem tipo o Placehold.it?
Tipo assim quando eu escrevo a tag IMG do HTML dentro do src eu passo um endereço que deverá retornar uma imagem.

Ex.:

```
<img src="http://meusite.com/350x150">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não sou lá essas coisas em php, mas eu sei que existe o GD (http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/ref.image.php) em php

Criando imagem dinamicamente através do metodo get (?width=300&height=300):

## Arquivo: imagem.php

```
<?php
header("Content-type:image/png"); // Informa ao nevagador que se trata de uma imagem png
$imagem=imagecreate($_GET["width"],$_GET["height"]); // Cria a imagem com as dimensões definidas
$preto=imagecolorallocate($imagem,0,0,0); // Cria um fundo preto
$branco=imagecolorallocate($imagem,255,255,255); // Armazena uma cor
imagestring($imagem,10,8,8,$_GET["width"]."x".$_GET["height"],$branco); // Escreve na imagem
imagepng($imagem);
imagedestroy($imagem);
?>
```

Depois é só chamar ela dentro de uma tag img, por exemplo:

```
<img src="imagem.php?width=800&height=600">
```

Comment: Matheus e no caso de eu ja ter a imagem pronta no disco como eu faço para retorna-la? Obrigado

Comment: Valeu já descobri. Muito obrigado pela ajuda.